# Can't run youtube file on terminal

Tags: python, terminal, youtube

I'm working on a personal project that is using this [Github Project](https://github.com/Jessime/youtube_history) to analyse my youtube data. The GitHub code itself seems to be fine because other people have got it to work however when I follow the instructions to run in on terminal I keep getting this error. I think I am pointing to the wrong file but I put the right path so not sure what could be going wrong?

```
(base) zawwarnaseer@apples-MBP ~ % $ cd youtube_history-master  
(base) zawwarnaseer@apples-MBP youtube_history-master % pip install -r requirements.txt
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /Users/zawwarnaseer/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: youtube_dl in /Users/zawwarnaseer/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (2021.12.17)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask in /Users/zawwarnaseer/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 3)) (1.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /Users/zawwarnaseer/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 4)) (1.21.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /Users/zawwarnaseer/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 5)) (1.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: plotly in /Users/zawwarnaseer/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 6)) (5.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wordcloud in /Users/zawwarnaseer/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 7)) (1.8.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in /Users/zawwarnaseer/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 8)) (4.11.1)
Requirement already satisfied: emoji in /Users/zawwarnaseer/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 9)) (1.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.2.1 in /Users/zawwarnaseer/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.0.9)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in /Users/zawwarnaseer/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (21.3)
Requirement already satisfied: fonttools>=4.22.0 in /Users/zawwarnaseer/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (4.25.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=6.2.0 in /Users/zawwarnaseer/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (9.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /Users/zawwarnaseer/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7 in /Users/zawwarnaseer/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in /Users/zawwarnaseer/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.15 in /Users/zawwarnaseer/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from Flask->-r requirements.txt (line 3)) (2.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10.1 in /Users/zawwarnaseer/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from Flask->-r requirements.txt (line 3)) (2.11.3)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in /Users/zawwarnaseer/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from Flask->-r requirements.txt (line 3)) (8.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in /Users/zawwarnaseer/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from Flask->-r requirements.txt (line 3)) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in /Users/zawwarnaseer/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pandas->-r requirements.txt (line 5)) (2022.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tenacity>=6.2.0 in /Users/zawwarnaseer/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from plotly->-r requirements.txt (line 6)) (8.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in /Users/zawwarnaseer/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from beautifulsoup4->-r requirements.txt (line 8)) (2.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /Users/zawwarnaseer/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10.1->Flask->-r requirements.txt (line 3)) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /Users/zawwarnaseer/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7->matplotlib->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.16.0)
(base) zawwarnaseer@apples-MBP youtube_history-master % python youtube_history.py --takeout downloads/Takeout
Welcome!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/zawwarnaseer/Downloads/youtube_history-master/youtube_history.py", line 373, in <module>
    analysis.run()
  File "/Users/zawwarnaseer/Downloads/youtube_history-master/youtube_history.py", line 352, in run
    self.download_data()
  File "/Users/zawwarnaseer/Downloads/youtube_history-master/youtube_history.py", line 153, in download_data
    raise ValueError(f'"{watch_history}" is not a file. Did you download your YouTube data? ')
ValueError: "downloads/Takeout/YouTube and YouTube Music/history/watch-history.html" is not a file. Did you download your YouTube data?
```

Comment: `downloads/Takeout/Youtube and Youtube Music/history/watch-history.html/YouTube and YouTube Music/history/watch-history.html` is duplicated. How are you getting this value?

Comment: the GitHub instructions said to point to the /path/to/Takeout (as in the google takeout files) so that's what I tried to call

Comment: Consider to edit the code of the `youtube_history.py` file - specially at [line 151](https://github.com/Jessime/youtube_history/blob/1773b5c30a535deca0bf892cb173e645f0597f4f/youtube_history.py#L151) to see the value of "self". Also, are you calling this code as: `python youtube_history.py --takeout downloads/Takeout/Youtube\ and\ Youtube\ Music/history/watch-history.html`? - try just `python youtube_history.py --takeout downloads/Takeout`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Update: thank a lot for your help. I adjusted the line 151 to just read `watch_history = self.takeout` instead of `watch_history = self.takeout / 'YouTube and YouTube Music/history/watch-history.html'`. I no longer get the same error but now my terminal says it is 'Extracting video urls from Takeout.' and it's stuck there @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes

Comment: I was calling the wrong file. I have corrected my mistake however now I get the following message on my terminal. 

`(base) zawwarnaseer@apples-MBP ~ % cd downloads/youtube_history-master
(base) zawwarnaseer@apples-MBP youtube_history-master % python youtube_history.py --takeout /Users/zawwarnaseer/Downloads/Takeout
Welcome!
Extracting video urls from Takeout.`


it's stuck on this message and nothing happens afterwards. Wondering if theres something I'm missing or could anyone provide any help as to what might be going on?